# How do I download duplicates of imported contacts in the past month?

Tags: import, duplicate-contacts

I import contacts almost every day, and I automatically press "skip" on the "For Duplicate Contacts" import option.

When the import is complete, I recognize that I have the ability to download the duplicate emails.

However, I have NOT been doing that.

So now, I want to download all of the duplicates emails in the month of June.

So is there any way to retrieve all of the duplicate contacts from June?

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.16.

Comment: Can you clarify the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid those are gone.  By definition, those items aren't saved anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - i realise i misread this totally. So you 'skip' and therefore don't know who was a Duplicate if you don't grab the files? Aren't these 'Duplicates' recorded in files in sites/default/files/civicrm/upload? That is where we go to find import files and import error files if we have to dig them out